# CORS: Missing Authorization Header in Response (jQuery / Spring)

Tags: spring, rest, spring-security, cors, jwt

I have one Spring-Boot Web-Server running on localhost:8080 and an Apache HTTP-Server with some "static" html/js on localhost:80. I implemented a RESTful-API with JWT-Authorization.

If I do serve the static html/js on the same server as the REST-API, I successfully retrieve the JWT-Token as "Authorization"-Header, when I request the /login-Endpoint.

But as I do the same, serving the static sources on my Apache Server, the Authorization-Header is missing. My Javascript:

```
 $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "http://localhost:8080/login",
            data: JSON.stringify(data),
            contentType: "application/json",
            dataType: "json",
            success: function (data) {
                alert(data);
            },
            failure: function (errMsg) {
                alert(errMsg);
            },
            complete: function (resp) {
                console.log(resp.getAllResponseHeaders());
                console.log(resp.getResponseHeader("authorization"));
            }
        });
```

console.log(resp.getAllResponseHeaders()):

```
pragma: no-cache cache-control: no-cache, no-store, max-age=0, must-revalidate expires: 0
```

console.log(resp.getResponseHeader("authorization")):

```
null
```

I already did a lot of research and I think the reason is a faulty CORS-Configuration.

My WebSecurity-Class looks like this - trying to allow as much as I can (for testing purposes):

```
@EnableWebSecurity public class WebSecurity extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

@Autowired
private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

@Autowired
private UserDetailsServiceImpl userDetailsService;

@Override
protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http.cors().and().csrf().disable().authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, SecurityConstants.SIGN_UP_URL).permitAll().anyRequest().authenticated().and()
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthenticationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            .addFilter(new JWTAuthorizationFilter(authenticationManager()))
            // this disables session creation on Spring Security
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS);
}

@Override
public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
    auth.userDetailsService(userDetailsService).passwordEncoder(passwordEncoder);
}

 @Bean
    public CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("*"));
        configuration.setAllowedHeaders(Arrays.asList("*"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }}
```

Any further suggestions?

(I debugged my Java-Code and the JWT-Token successfully get added to the response - but my js doesn't receive it..)

Comment: Usually the JWTAuthorizationFilter works with authorization header. the filter validates the jwt in the header Authorization. 
 Please look the link below to get to know more about JWTAuthorizationFilter https://auth0.com/blog/implementing-jwt-authentication-on-spring-boot/

Comment: You should pass the Authorization header in the AJAX request to get the successful result or remove the filter from CORS

Comment: @VinuBibin : This is exactly the resource i used for building up Spring-setup. And as I mentioned - if the html/js sources are served on the same server everything works fine. But if the html/js-sources are served on a different server (CORS) the Authorization Header is missing..

Comment: Could you add a trace of request and response with header to your question? Also show the error message in your browser (use the dev tool of your browser).

Answer (score 0):

Your CORS config doesn't seems correct to me.

There are many levels at which you can Configure CORS in Spring

**Global CORS configuration**

Enabling CORS for the whole application is as simple as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class WebConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
        registry.addMapping("/**");
    }
}
```

If you are using Spring Boot, it is recommended to just declare a WebMvcConfigurer bean

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public WebMvcConfigurer corsConfigurer() {
        return new WebMvcConfigurerAdapter() {
            @Override
            public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
                registry.addMapping("/**");
            }
        };
    }
}
```

**Method Level**

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @CrossOrigin
    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

**Class Level**

```
@CrossOrigin
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/account")
public class AccountController {

    @GetMapping("/{id}")
    public Account retrieve(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }

    @DeleteMapping("/{id}")
    public void remove(@PathVariable Long id) {
        // ...
    }
}
```

More Detail [here](https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/08/cors-support-in-spring-framework)

**Edit 1**

If you are using Spring Security you can configure like this

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
            // by default uses a Bean by the name of corsConfigurationSource
            .cors().and()
            ...
    }

    @Bean
    CorsConfigurationSource corsConfigurationSource() {
        CorsConfiguration configuration = new CorsConfiguration();
        configuration.setAllowedOrigins(Arrays.asList("https://example.com"));
        configuration.setAllowedMethods(Arrays.asList("GET","POST"));
        UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource source = new UrlBasedCorsConfigurationSource();
        source.registerCorsConfiguration("/**", configuration);
        return source;
    }
}
```

More Detail [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/reference/html/cors.html)

Comment: There is no such global CORS configuration. Your *global* configuration is only for the Spring MVC dispatcher servlet. It is more local than Spring Security's configuration in OP's question, which works for all URLs unless you are ignoring some URLs explicitly.

Comment: Ya I missed Security Part. Thanks for the catch.  I have updated my answer.